# Single edit/insert of SOLR based off of an unique id

Tags: php, solr

Is anyone aware of how to write a single edit/insert to SOLR in PHP? I have the delta and full insert/edit working very well. But I am looking for a way to add a single document. I am guessing this would be a separate item on the data-config.xml file, and you would need to pass the unique ID to add, but I can not get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLR Docs](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages)

```
$doc = above link info
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service( $address, 8080, $path);
    try {
        $solr->add($doc);
     }
      catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();

      }
```